# Is it dangerous if saliva enters the hole in a tooth to be filled during a root canal or cavity treatment?

Tags: dentistry, root-canal

Since there are bacteria in saliva, would it be problematic if saliva goes under the filling?

The abstract of [this paper](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/3552638/) by
Mejàre *et al* notes:

> bacteria originating from saliva contamination do not seem to survive under tightly sealed composite resin restorations

However, [this paper](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/22422085/) by Wang *et al* shows that the presence of certain disease-causing bacteria is associated with their presence in saliva.

> The prevalence of E. faecalis was 19% in the saliva and 38% in the root canals. The odds that root canals harbored E. faecalis were increased if the saliva habored this bacterium (odds ratio=9.7; 95% confidence interval=1.8-51.6; P<0.05).

From what I can see, the research on this topic seem to be lacking. The dentists I visited never mention anything about it either.

References:
Mejàre, Ingegerd, Bertil Mejàre, and Stig Edwardsson. "Effect of a tight seal on survival of bacteria in saliva‐contaminated cavities filled with composite resin." Dental Traumatology 3.1 (1987): 6-9.
Wang, Qian-Qian, et al. "Prevalence of Enterococcus faecalis in saliva and filled root canals of teeth associated with apical periodontitis." International journal of oral science 4.1 (2012): 19-23.

Comment: I edited out any mention of licking since it's oddly specific and you also ask about saliva in general.

Comment: It seems from your second source that the answer is self evident.  It seems the filling needs to be improperly done, though, and the paper notes that normal/healthy mouths don't usually have E.faecalis as part of normal mouth biomes.